# String modifiers not working in sscanf in kernel.h

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scanf

```
#include <linux/kernel.h> //sscanf

int err;
char a[32];
char b[32];
char c[32];
char test[20]="add abc de";
char *p=test;
err=sscanf(p,"%s %[^\t\n] %s",a,b,c);
printk("%d Data correctly parsed %s %s %s",err,a,b,c);
```

It prints the following instead of the strings from the array.

```
\xfffffff4sa\xffffff82\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff
```

The problem is the second modifier, if I use a normal `%s` it works. I want to store all the words between two words in only a string.
e.g. `delete a b c fromTable` store `a b c` in a string.

The code above works with the sscanf from the C library but not with the one from kernel.h

Comment: It appears you might be [misusing `printk()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-basics.html). Starting with a number might cause problems given the `KERN_*` macros are numbers. Verify your usage is correct, that you've included all proper headers, and you aren't getting any warnings.  Something else could be wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think it uses the default ```KERN_LOG```, everything is correct, if I just use ```%s``` instead it works correctly.

Comment: Try a format string like `"err: %d Data correctly parsed %s %s %s"` so the output doesn't start with a number.  I vaguely remember something about `printk()` from some Linux kernel module work I did in the past.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Its the same ```Err: 1 Data correctly parsed add  \xfffffff4sa\xffffff82\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff``` It gets only the first modifier the second just doesn't work.

Comment: The kernel version of `sscanf()` is not the same as the libc implementation. I'm having trouble finding any detailed documentation, but there are other questions about bugs and differences from standard `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `sscanf` returns the number of items matched. Returning value 1 means that only the first argument - `a` has been assigned.

Support for `%[...]` specifier has been appeared only in 4.6 version: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6-rc1/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L2736. And they provide the following warning:

```
        /*
         * Warning: This implementation of the '[' conversion specifier
         * deviates from its glibc counterpart in the following ways:
         * (1) It does NOT support ranges i.e. '-' is NOT a special
         *     character
         * (2) It cannot match the closing bracket ']' itself
         * (3) A field width is required
         * (4) '%*[' (discard matching input) is currently not supported
         *
         * Example usage:
         * ret = sscanf("00:0a:95","%2[^:]:%2[^:]:%2[^:]",
         *      buf1, buf2, buf3);
         * if (ret < 3)
         *    // etc..
         */
```

Among other things, this warning says that specifier `%[..]` **requires** a field width. In your code you don't provide that width, so the argument `b` cannot be parsed.